# Rails 4 Whitelist IP's to Single Route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have a form within my public page that I would like to lock down to internal IP ranges. I have been looking around at the answers to other questions in this vein but they envelope the whole site, I would like to be able to restrict this to just a handful of pages. What I did find was this for Rails 3 in the `ApplicationController`

```
before_filter :protect

def protect
  @ips = ['127.0.0.1', '203.123.10.1'] #And so on ...]
  if not @ips.include? request.remote_ip
     # Check for your subnet stuff here, for example
     # if not request.remote_ip.include?('127.0,0')
     render :text => "You are unauthorized"
     return
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at rack-attack,
https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack

Example:

```
Rack::Attack.blocklist('block 1.2.3.4 on login') do |req|
  # Requests are blocked if the return value is truthy
  req.path == '/login' && '1.2.3.4' == req.ip
end
```

Comment: I have not, I will look into it.

Comment: @lostrennie It looks like a great/simple solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a constraint class like so:

```
class DomainConstraint
  def initialize
    @domains = ['127.0.0.1', '203.123.10.1']
  end

  def matches?(request)
    @domains.include? request.domain
  end
end
```

And then implement it in your `routes.rb`:

```
constraints DomainConstraint.new do
  get 'protected_routes'
end
```